# How to start a new Android Studio project with all the code from my previous app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile

Hi there I made a dog themed app, and would like to use the exact code, layouts and drawables as the starting template for my new app which will be similar.

How do I load my previous apps code into my new android studio project, I can only see how to load the original project, not just the code from the original project.

Answer (score 0):

just load your whole project in a new windows and extract the resources you need from that project, go to your main project folder and paste those resources into your res - drawable , the same with the code but paste it inside your classes.

Android Studio is not like netbeans that you can add multiple projects to the project tree, you need to open them in different instances

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a copy of your project and open it as a new one project. you may change some variable for the configuration but nothing serious.